# Using objdump/readelf and extern variable

Tags: c, gcc, elf, extern, ld

I have library `ab.so` compose of 2 sources file `a.m`, `a.h` and `b.m`, `b.h`

In `a.m` I have define a variable `foo` and in `b.m` I have declare it `extern`.

Now using readelf/objdump I would like to know where and how can I see my variable foo in the `a.o` file, `b.o` and `ab.so`?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky question. You must realize that *readelf/objdump* will not display C code as a result, only assembly code. If you are prepared to read that, go ahead and disassembly the application with `objdump -d ab.so` and look for the relevant code there.

There are a bunch of *readelf/objdump* tutorials available on the web. Don't be afraid to look for them.

Comment: http://www.linuxforums.org/articles/understanding-elf-using-readelf-and-objdump_125.html